# Log4j2 - Compressing aged Rollover Files, keep last X file uncompressed

Tags: apache, logging, compression, log4j2

How to compress **only older rolled files** and not every time it rolls? (now it is every day). The following configuration only rolls daily and delete compressed file after 60 days, but it compresses every day.

I don't want to use a tool to decompress the file of the last [X] days if I have to investigate in them...

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="file" fileName="${baseDir}/app-trace.log"
               filePattern="${baseDir}/app-trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"
               immediateFlush="false" append="true">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %c - %m%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="91">
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
            <IfFileName glob="*/app-trace*.log.gz">
                <IfLastModified age="60d">
                    <IfAny>
                        <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="1 GB"/>
                        <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="10"/>
                    </IfAny>
                </IfLastModified>
            </IfFileName>
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I ended up doing my own implementation of a DeleteAction, and attaching it to a DefaultRolloverStrategy, so that it is zipping everything before deleting. You can find the sourcecode at:

https://github.com/lqbweb/log4j2-ZipDelete

Comment: Hello @lqbweb.
I am trying to use your ZipDeleteAction, but I am not clear how the zipPattern parameter should be set in regards to the filePattern in the RolloingFileApender. Should the filePattern be adjusted (like omitting %i or %d) to make file names matching what the ZipDeleteAction takes as an input? An example of the whole <RollingFile> configuration section would be very helpful.